# Updating "field by field": copying data from one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, which are basically the same except the name: one for actual data second one for backup. And what I want to do is to update fields in first one using the content from the other one - checking field by field based on ID.

Let's say it should looks like this:

1. Get the first row.
2. FIRST_TABLE(ID_FT, NAME_FT) and SECOND_TABLE(ID_ST, NAME_ST),
3. If ID_FT == ID_ST then NAME_FT = NAME_ST,
4. Get the next row,
5. Go to point 3 and loop until end of the FIRST_TABLE.

What queries should I use? How iterating through the table in ORACLE/SQL looks like?

Comment: Would it make sense to use a database backup tool to backup the table instead?

Comment: Well - the system is a little bit complicated and it have to contain additional backup table because it allows avoiding some problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement.

Test data:

```
SQL> create table FIRST_TABLE (
2 ID_FT number(20),
3 NAME_FT varchar2(200));
4 create table SECOND_TABLE (
5 ID_ST number(20),
6 NAME_ST varchar2(200));
7 insert into FIRST_TABLE (ID_FT,NAME_FT) values (1,null);
8 insert into FIRST_TABLE (ID_FT,NAME_FT) values (2,null);
9 insert into SECOND_TABLE (ID_ST,NAME_ST) values (1,'ST1');
10 insert into SECOND_TABLE (ID_ST,NAME_ST) values (2,'ST2');
11 insert into SECOND_TABLE (ID_ST,NAME_ST) values (3,'ST3');
12 commit;
```

Query:

```
SQL> merge into first_table t1
2 using second_table t2
3 on (t1.id_ft = t2.id_st)
4 when matched then update set t1.name_ft = t2. name_st;
5 commit;
6 select * from first_table;

ID_FT       NAME_FT 
---------- ---------- 
  1         ST1
  2         ST2
```

Also, if you will use `MERGE`, you can insert data in first_table if it's missing.

```
SQL> merge into first_table t1
2 using second_table t2
3 on (t1.id_ft = t2.id_st)
4 when matched then update set t1.name_ft = t2. name_st
5 when not matched then insert (t1.id_ft,t1.name_ft) values (t2.id_st,t2.name_st);
6 commit;
7 select * from first_table;

ID_FT       NAME_FT 
---------- ---------- 
  1         ST1
  2         ST2
  3         ST3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want an update with a correlated subquery:

```
update first_table ft
    set name_ft = (select t2.name_st from second_table st where ft.ID_FT = st.ID_ST)
    where exists (select t2.name_st from second_table st where ft.ID_FT = st.ID_ST);
```